How to display custom API error messages client side with Auth.js?
I am trying to setup my Credential provider so that when the user fails to login (wrong username/password, for example) I can display the error message returned by the API in the client side.
This is my auth.ts file:
export const { handlers, signIn, signOut, auth } = NextAuth({
  providers: [
    Credentials({
        credentials: {
          email: {},
          password: {},
        },
        authorize: async (credentials) => {
          let data = {
            email: credentials.email as string,
            password: credentials.password as string,
          }
  
          try {
            const user = await AuthService.login(data);
            return user;
          } catch(error: any) {
            throw new Error(error?.message || error);
          }
        },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async session({ session, token }) {
      session.user = token.user as any;
      return session;
    },
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      if (user) {
        token.user = user;
      }
      return token;
    },
    async signIn({ user }) {
      const userData = user as any;
      if (userData?.error) {
        throw new Error(userData?.error);
      }
      return true;
    },
  },
})

Successful logins work fine and returns the user data. The issue is when the user fails to log in. I can see the API response message in the console but when I try to print via console.log the response in the client side I get this object:
{
    "error": "Configuration",
    "code": null,
    "status": 200,
    "ok": true,
    "url": null
}

Whereas in the console I get the correct message saying:
[auth][error] AccessDenied: Read more at https://errors.authjs.dev#accessdenied
[auth][cause]: Error: "Username/Password Incorrect.

This is my submit function on the login form:
const onSubmit = (values: FormData) => {
    const data = {
        email: values.email,
        password: values.password,
        redirect: false
    }

    signIn("credentials", data);
};

How can I get the actual API response message that I can see in the console and when I do console.log in the auth.js file on the client side?
Thanks in advance.

yout next-auth version

https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/9900#issuecomment-2273925589 there  is a github issue regarding that

@DileepaMabulage I am using version 5.0.0-beta.20

https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/11190 This is the issue I raised regarding the exact question. https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/pull/11469 they closed it with the fix

@DileepaMabulageI I see so apparently in the version I am using (5.0.0-beta.20) it is fixed? Do I have something wrong in my code that is preventing me from showing the error?

I managed to get the error showing in the client by following the method outlined on this post: https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/discussions/8999#discussioncomment-10107786 but now what happens is that the session status doesn't changes to authenticated unless I refresh the whole page. Previously it did so without issue.
